# Стоит ли учить Python 3.0, если новая версия - 3.8?

Tags: python, python-3.x, youtube

Искал в общем видеокурсы на YouTube по Python 3. Нашел курс Гоши Дударя трехлетней давности, в котором он учит версии 3.0. Стоит ли учить Python 3.0, и чем он отличается от Python 3.8?

Comment: Не надо учить по ютьюбу: книги, доки и т.д.

Comment: @VictorVosMottor Зато из него ничего не вырастет и на фрилансе заказ уйдет не ему, а тебе например)

Answer (score 2):

Если вы только начинаете учить язык, то вы скорее всего не заметите разницы между 3.0 и 3.8, т.к. основы языка не менялись

Comment: но у гоши дударя учиться не надо

Comment: @timur согласен =)

Comment: А что плохого?.